# Cannot authenticate to Digital Ocean Kubernetes through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, digital-ocean

I am working on a system that is spread across both Digital Ocean and AWS.  Their Node.js instances are on a Kubernetes cluster on Digital Ocean and their databases and S3 spaces are hosted on AWS.  I was able to connect to the Kubernetes cluster using kubectl.  Then, I was able to do a 'terraform init' with no issues.  But, when I tried to do a 'terraform plan', I got this error.

Error: Error retrieving Kubernetes cluster: GET https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/kubernetes/clusters/1234: 401 Unable to authenticate you.

I am new to both Kubernetes and Terraform.  Does Terraform expect the Kubernetes config information to be in a different place then where kubectl expects it?

Comment: BTW, I know that my terraformrc file is correct.  When I run terraform plan, I am able to get a lock on my workspace.

Comment: Have you configured your digital ocean api token? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-terraform-with-digitalocean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a token so that Digital Ocean’s servers know that you have permission to access your account.
Follow the steps in the instruction [creating-access-token](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/api/create-personal-access-token/) and copy the token to your clipboard.Remember to store it as an environment variable:
`export TF_VAR_do_token=your-token`.

Set environment variables:

```
export TF_VAR_do_token=your_digital_ocean_token

export TF_VAR_do_cluster_name=your_cluster_name
```

Otherwise problem is with the API token. Create a new token and then the operation will succeeded.

Useful blog article about setting up [Kubernetes cluster wit Digital Ocean and Terraform](https://web.archive.org/web/20190314161613/https://ponderosa.io/blog/kubernetes/2019/03/13/terraform-cluster-create/).